# Google script: How to hide a row if a cell contains a date 10 days older than today's date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where cells in column B contain automatically set dates.
If the difference between today and those dates is greater than 10 days, I would like to hide the corresponding rows.

I have tried to code it as it follows but I am stuck and I need help, please:

```
 function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");   // The name of the sheet    
    var row = s.getRange('B:B').getValues(); // it's the column that contains cells with dates 
    var today = new Date(); // today's date
    
    s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
    for(var i=0; i< row.length; i++){ if(today - row[i]>10 ) { s.hideRows(i+1, 1); } 
         
    }}
```

Any suggestions about how to fix the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regular function:**

If you want to do that **iteratively** for all the cells in **column B** then you can use a **regular** function and execute it from the script editor:

```
function myFunction(){

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const today = new Date();
  
  const check_values = sh.getRange('A1:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const date_values = sh.getRange('B1:B'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  
  date_values.forEach((d,index)=>{
                      
     var diffTime = Math.abs(today - d);  
     const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
     if (diffDays > 10 && check_values[index]=='Yes'){
        sh.hideRows(index+1);
     }
  })
  }
```

---

**onEdit(e) function:**

If you want an `onEdit(e)` function, namely check whether you need to hide the row or not when you **edit** a cell in **column B**, then use:

```
function onEdit(e){

  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  
  const today = new Date();
  const date2 = new Date(e.range.getValue());
  const diffTime = Math.abs(today - date2);
  const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
  
  if ( as.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 2 && diffDays > 10){ 
  as.hideRows(row);
  }
}
```

---

In both cases, make sure that the dates in **column B** in **Sheet1** are actually **date objects** and not texts. To check that, use the formula `=isdate(B1)` and if that returns *true* it means that B1 is a date object.

---

**References:**

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

Comment: Thanks Marios! it is perfect!  Is it possible to add a condition? That is, if values in column A = "Yes" and  dates in column B are >10 days, then hide row?
I'd like to implement this logic in the regular function

Comment: @Stefano check my updated answer (regular function).

Comment: Thank you so much, Marios! it is much appreciated!